# Passing PHP Array to Javascript with Json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, maps

I am trying to pass a php array to a javascript variable as an object to use in google maps on the same page/file. I am not able to send out an alert when testing the array in javascript.

PHP

```
while( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ){
$street_address = $row['street_address'];
$zip = $row['zip'];
$state = $row['state'];
$lat = $row['lat'];
$lng = $row['lng'];
$test = $row['sellerDB_test'];

$firstName = $row['first_name'];
$lastName = $row['last_name'];
$email = $row['email'];
$phone = $row['phone'];

/* Each row is added as a new array */
$locations = array( 'streetAddress'=>$street_address, 'state'=>$state, 'zip'=>$zip, 'lat'=>$lat, 'lng'=>$lng, 'test'=>$test, 'first name'=>$firstName, 'last name'=>$lastName, 'email'=>$email, 'phone'=>$phone);
```

JS

```
var map;
        var Markers = {};
        var infowindow;
        var locations = '<?php echo json_encode($locations); ?>';
        var location = JSON.parse(loactions);
        alert(locations[0]);
```

I am getting this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: loactions is not defined
>       at account:299

Comment: JS code is in php file with `<script>` tag?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay yes!

Comment: check your `locations`, which line is `account:299`?

Comment: are you expecting multiple rows? initialize `$locations` outside the loop, the continually push inside while, `$locations[] = array(... blah blah data)`, then outside use the echo. inside js, no need for quotations, just outright echo it: `var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations); ?>;`, so that you don't need `JSON.parse`

Comment: @user3780248 are you following the answers?

Comment: @Ghost Thanks! That helped alot but now when I try to send out an alert I get a [Object Object]. I tried alert(locations.streetAddress) and alert(locations[0])

Comment: @user3780248 of course `alert(locations[0]);` won't give you what you expect, you'll need to go deeper inside by using a loop to access the data

Comment: @Ghost Thank you ghost, I have learned alot from your teachings :) alert(JSON.stringify(locations[0]['streetAddress']));

Comment: sure glad this hellped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ghost is right. I did not notice that the $locations is inside `while` loop. So You should define `$locations = [];` before while loop.
And then keep adding multiple records from while loop. So the updated code should be like:

```
$locations = [];
while( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ){
    $street_address = $row['street_address'];
    $zip = $row['zip'];
    $state = $row['state'];
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lng = $row['lng'];
    $test = $row['sellerDB_test'];

    $firstName = $row['first_name'];
    $lastName = $row['last_name'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];

    /* Each row is added as a new array [] */ 
    $locations[] = array( 'streetAddress'=>$street_address, 'state'=>$state, 'zip'=>$zip, 'lat'=>$lat, 'lng'=>$lng, 'test'=>$test, 'first name'=>$firstName, 'last name'=>$lastName, 'email'=>$email, 'phone'=>$phone);
}
```

And after this, you should put the JS code snippet.

And use it like this:

JS cpde:

```
var map;
var Markers = {};
var infowindow;
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations); ?>;
var location = JSON.parse(loactions);
alert(location.streetAddress);
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot but now when I try to send out an alert I get a [Object Object]. I tried alert(locations.streetAddress) and alert(locations[0])

Comment: @user3780248, you are storing parsed json data to `location` not `locations` so access the data like `location.streetAddress` and you will get the values.

Comment: Your welcome @user3780248. Happy to help. Updating my answer so it will be helpful to others.